# jQuery hover keeps firing non-stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that i intend to be "covered" until the user moves his mouse over it. To do this, i have a div that is placed on top of the form via z-index and absolute positioning which will be hidden when the user hovers his mouse over it, causing the form to be visible.

Form:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div id='form-cover' class='form-cover'>
        <div id='sign-up'>Sign up today!</div>
    </div>

    <form id='register' class='form' method='POST' action='#'>
        <label for='first-name'>First Name: </label>
        <input id='first-name' type='text' length='50'>
        <br />
        <label for='last-name'>Last Name: </label>
        <input id='last-name' type='text' length='50'>
        <br />
        <label for='address'>Address: </label>
        <input id='Address' type='text' length='50'>
    </form>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#form-cover').hover(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    },function(){
        $(this).show();
});
```

Currently when i move my mouse over the #form-cover, the covering div keeps hiding and then showing itself repeatedly, when i only intend for it to just hide itself and show itself again when the user's mouse leaves the form.

What i've tried

```
$('#form-cover').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    //$('#form-cover').removeClass('form-cover');
});
$('#form-cover').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).show();
    //$('#form-cover').addClass('form-cover');
});
```

as well as chaining mouseenter and mouseleave together but nothing seems to be working.

Any help rendered would be much appreciated!

The fiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/KXW72/

Comment: Your mouseleave should not be bound to form-cover, since you want to show it when the mouse leaves the form itself. I think you should hide the cover permanently when the user hovers, to have to hover the form just to see it is a bad user experience

Comment: @Huangism i understand where you are coming from but i plan on having multiple forms, so i'm planning on using the cover to cover the forms which the user is not currently on, and this was simply the idea i came up with. I would be interested in hearing any other suggestions you might have =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your form cover hides and thus fires the mouse leave.

Try:

```
$('#form-cover').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).hide(); 
});
$('#business').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#form-cover').show(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KXW72/1/

Comment: I can't believe i didn't think of that haha,that was a short and sweet answer to get it working

Comment: No problems :)  It's something I've done numerous times in the past and been scratching my head until I realised it.